# Cannot coerce String (11/17/1993) to Date

Tags: java, mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

Feel like I've tried literally every single permutation of as Date format, as String as Date, as String, etc. What on earth am I doing wrong?

Trying to feed data into SF from a CSV. Simple birthday field. Comes in as:

10/29/2003 in an Excel column.

Keep getting this error:

```
Cannot coerce String (11/17/1993) to Date, caused by: Text '11/17/1993'
```

```
Date_of_Birth__c: $."Date of Birth" as Date {format: "YYYY-M-dd" }
```

Also tried..

```
$."Date of Birth" as Date as String{format : "YYYY-DD-MM"}
```

Can anyone help me figure out why I cannot seemingly turn a simple string format around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a format that doesn't match the input data. Clearly the date is using format month-day-year. You are using format year-month-date or year-date-month which fails to parse the date. Additionally you are using incorrect formatting patterns. DataWeave uses [Java patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for parsing/formatting dates. The meaning of those patters is different for uppercase and lowercase characters. You should almost always use `dd` (day of month), `MM` (month of year) and `yyyy` (year). Using `DD` (day of year) and `YYYY` (week based year) will not work for normal dates.

Instead try using the right format: `{format: "MM-dd-yyyy" }`